# How to fix list comprehension 'bitwise_and' error and optimize for-loop?

Tags: python, performance, for-loop, list-comprehension

I have the following for loop below, but I want to make this into a more computationally efficient variant. I thought I could do that with list comprehension, but this is giving me the following error: `TypeError: ufunc 'bitwise_and' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''`

EDIT I: I am trying to compare input1 and input2 and if input1 is larger than than input2, then the difference should be squared and scaled by the scaler. Otherwise, a value of zero should be assigned to the output.

How can I fix this and are there any other way to speed this up even more?

```
# Input variables
input1 = np.array([0.5, 1, 3, 7, 10])
input2 = np.array([0.5, 1.5, 2, 7, 8])
scaler = 3

# For loop
output = np.zeros(len(input1))
for i in range(len(input1)):
    if input1[i] > input2[i]:
        output[i] = scaler * (input1[i] - input2[i])**2  
    else: 
        output[i] = 0      

# List comprehension attempt, but gives error.
output = [scaler * (input1-input2)**2 for i in input1 & input2 if input1 > input2]
```

Comment: Clearly it's a syntax error but without knowing what you're actually trying to achieve it's hard to say how you should do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are *only* trying to optimise the for loop with a list comprehension, the following is equivalent:

```py
# Input variables
input1 = np.array([0.5, 1, 3, 7, 10])
input2 = np.array([0.5, 1.5, 2, 7, 8])
scaler = 3

# List comprehension
output = [scaler * (x-y)**2 if x>y else 0 for (x,y) in zip(input1,input2)]
```

EDIT: This is probably faster as numpy can vectorise the operation

```
# Numpy operations
arr = input1-input2
arr = arr.clip(min=0)
output = scaler * arr ** 2
```

Comment: @Haukland I need to wait for 5 minutes, but will accept it.

Comment: @meistef, try with the numpy implementation

Answer (score 1):

You are doing list compresension wrong.

If you want to

```py
output = [scaler * (i1-i2)**2 if i1 > i2 else 0 for (i1, i2) in zip(input1, input2)]

print(output)
```

Comment: This seems to work! However, I would like to add an else-statement that when i1 is not larger than i2 then store a value 0 for that index. How can I add this?

Comment: @meistef [f(x) if condition else g(x) for ...]

Comment: Just move the if condition to the return value and add else 0 :)